# Area Attribute in Feature Classes Gets Renamed to full FeatureClassName.AREA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, fields-attributes, limitations

I have a number of feature classes in an Oracle-backed Enterprise Geodatabase which have an attribute called "AREA" which is type double. All of these feature classes are part of the database user/schema called "AMIS". The problem, is that the attribute is automatically getting renamed to the AMIS.FeatureClassName.AREA.  For example, in the feature class called CAMP_AREA, the AREA field is getting called "AMIS.CAMP_AREA.AREA". I have tried deleting the field and re-adding "AREA" again, and it just defaults to "AMIS.CAMP_AREA.AREA".

[image]

I've checked the list of [Oracle Reserved Words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm#CJHIIICD), and AREA is not one of them.

I have actually also seen this behaviour on a Microsoft SQL Server-backed Geodatabase with the same results.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that while AREA is not an Oracle reserved word, the reason I have also seen this on Microsoft SQL-Backed geodatabases as well, is that AREA is, in fact, a [fully qualified geodatabase word](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/design-defining-fields-in-tables.htm).

That link actually states my exact issue:

> Certain field names appear in ArcGIS with their fully qualified names
> for tables stored within an enterprise geodatabase. For example, if
> you create or import a polygon feature class that contains a field
> named Area, the database, schema, and table name are appended to it.
> This is the name you see in the attribute table of the feature class.
> That means for a polygon feature class named archsites, stored in the
> prof schema of the museum database, the Area field would look like
> this:
>
> `MUSEUM.PROF.ARCHSITES.AREA`

The full list of fully qualified field names in a geodatabase are:

```
FID, AREA, LEN, POINTS, NUMOFPTS, ENTITY, EMINX, EMINY, EMAXX, EMAXY, EMINZ, EMAXZ, MIN_MEASURE, MAX_MEASURE
```